# Can't change lower-case-table-names on MariaDB

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mariadb

I tried to upload my WordPress on AWS EC2 Server, but when I import my database MariaDB is changing my table name with only lower case character

I tried to add in etc/my.cnf :

```
[mysqld]
lower-case-table-names=2
```

I tried too

```
[mysqld]
lower-case-table-names=1
```

I restarted my MariaDB with :

```
sudo service mariadb restart
```

But when I'm looking to know if variable is changed of global variable with :

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW variables LIKE "%low%";
```

I have :

```
lower_case_table_names                  | 0
```

And I can't import my database with uppercase letter, how can I change this variable ? It is possible on AWS EC2 ?

Comment: Changing that variable is tricky.  Have you studied https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html  And it could be that AWS prevents changing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just restarted completely my AWS EC2 server and now it's working

Answer (score 0):

Maybe another config file overrides that value:

- /etc/my.cnf  -> Global
- /etc/mysql/my.cnf -> Global
- SYSCONFDIR/my.cnf -> Global
- $MYSQL_HOME/my.cnf ->    Server
- defaults-extra-file  File specified with --defaults-extra-file=path, if any
- ~/.my.cnf    -> User

Check here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/configuring-mariadb-with-mycnf/

Comment: I grep my.cnf at root, and I got only this config file

Comment: It could have a different name.